# Recovering an ancient YouTube account

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-recovery

I have a YouTube account that dates from at least 2011, before the Google Accounts were fully integrated.

I know the username and the email address, but not the password.

Here's where it gets tricky. The email address no longer exists, but I own the domain and could recreate it. It's using Google Apps.

If I recreate that Google account on the domain I own, will I then be able to either a) automatically link it back to that YouTube account based on the email address matching or b) recover the password?

I'm not hopeful on the latter, because when I go to [the Gaia link](https://www.youtube.com/gaia_link), click "I cannot access my account", and enter the email address in the [account recovery page](https://www.youtube.com/account_recovery) it takes me to a Google account recovery form.

Answer (score 1):

YouTube accounts created after 2009 or accessed after 2011 always have a Google account attached to them, so the Gaia link probably won't work for you.

I'm afraid you'll have to try the Google account recovery. Note that you can have a Google account with a non-Gmail email address.

Comment: I agree.  Although it seems persistent about using the mobile number.  But some years ago when I had forgotten the password to a gmail account and did not have a mobile connected, they charged me $1.00 for the recovery effort.